# Circle Border not animating on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate the border of a circle when I hover over it so that it fills up gradually. So far no luck on my `@keyframes` animation code. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here as my keyframes is targeting the value of my `.circle:hover` property.

[image]

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5d0b3c;
}

#skills .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 18px sans-serif;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.circle:hover {
  animation: border;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    border: none;
  }
  25% {
    border: 5px solid pink;
  }
  50% {
  }
  75% {
  }
  100% {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" style="border: 1px solid">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <span class="text">skill 1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing incomplete "parameters" in CSS. When we are going to use an animation, the required parameter sequence is:

```
animation: [name] [duration] [interpolation function]
```

Interpolation function is how the animation will be executed: linearly? Will it start fast and end slowly? Or will you follow a custom rhythm?

Example:

```
animation: border 1s linear;
```

However, there are sub-parameters that you can use but are not required, such as deciding how long the animation will take to start. For more details, you can see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/).

Comment: I see. I want the border to rotate around it so it doesn't fill all at once. Like a progress bar of sorts

Comment: Ah yes. This process is done in building the animation in @keyframes, the way it is doing. In this case, what you are doing is ideal: use a percentage progress to make the border gradually appear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the CSS wrongly.

You only set the name of the animation, but that is not enough for it to understand what you really want to do. To do so, you need to give an `interpolation function` and a `duration`.

Beside that, I've also added `-webkit-animation` as that is needed for browsers like *Safari* and *Chrome*, although the latter won't support it from version 43, as far as I know.

Anyway, an example of correct CSS is this:

```
.circle:hover {
    -webkit-animation: border 1s linear;
  animation: border 1s linear;
}
```

Please see the full working code / demo here: 
**https://jsfiddle.net/9r08aoty/3/**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need animation / keyframes for that, a simple transition will do

```css
.circle {
  box-sizing:border-box; /* <<== so the circle doesn't grow with the border */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5d0b3c;
}

#skills .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 18px sans-serif;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.circle:hover {
  border:5px solid pink;
  transition:border .5s ease; /*<<== simple transition */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" style="border: 1px solid">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <span class="text">skill 1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```